# D3 Dependency Wheel not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dependencies

I am trying to construct a dependency wheel like this http://www.redotheweb.com/DependencyWheel/ for my packages. I have written the following code. But, my wheel is not rendering properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.redotheweb.com/DependencyWheel/js/d3.dependencyWheel.js"></script>
<script>
    <!-- My JSON is in following style -->
    json = JSON.parse('{"A":["B","C","D","E"],"B":["F"]}

    var packageNames = [];
    var obj = {}
    var matrix = [];
    for (var key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key) && !(key in obj)) {
            packageNames.push(key);
            obj[key] = true;
        }
        json[key].forEach(function (neighbor) {
            if (!(neighbor in obj)) {
                packageNames.push(neighbor);
                obj[neighbor] = true;
            }
        });
    }
    for (var package of packageNames) {
        matrix[packageNames.indexOf(package)] = [];
        if (json[package] != null) {
            json[package].forEach(function (neighbor) {
                matrix[packageNames.indexOf(package)][packageNames.indexOf(neighbor)] = 1;
            });
        }
    }

    console.log(matrix);
    console.log(packageNames);

    jQuery(function () {
        var chart = d3.chart.dependencyWheel();
        d3.select('#chart_placeholder')
            .datum({
                packageNames: packageNames,
                matrix: matrix
            })
            .call(chart);
    });
</script>
<div id="chart_placeholder"></div>
```

What I am seeing?

[image]

Besides, I am getting following errors in my console:
`Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,NaNA200,200 0 0,1 NaN,NaNQ 0,0 NaN,NaNA200,200 0 0,1 NaN,NaNQ 0,0 NaN,NaNZ"`
`Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute transform="rotate(NaN)"`

Could somebody please help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're creating the `matrix` array. You put the `1`'s in the right places, but `matrix` needs to be a square matrix ([docs here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Chord-Layout#matrix)) so the rest of the values should be `0`'s. Your `matrix` looks like this:

[image]

As a fix, I've created a 0-filled `matrix_row`, the length of `packageNames`, which can be added as you loop through each `package`:

```
// Define a new array, padded with zeros
var matrix_row = Array.apply(null, new Array(packageNames.length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,0);

for (var package of packageNames) {
    // Then add this 0-filled row for each package to create a square matrix
    matrix[packageNames.indexOf(package)] = matrix_row;
    if (json[package] != null) {
        // And now replace some of those 0s with 1s
        json[package].forEach(function (neighbor) {
            matrix[packageNames.indexOf(package)][packageNames.indexOf(neighbor)] = 1;
        });
    }
}
```

Here's a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/FeGSNFx5xd4MRKg1qG6U?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Henry. Wanted to ask if there is a way I can show the dependents and dependencies as tooltip on hover?